# Adding content to an element created dynamically in Backbone with Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a Backbone View in Rails 3 where the initialize has a line which dynamically creates a div with a class like this

```
initialize: () ->
  $('body').append('<div class="new"></div>')
```

The contents of the div are in a eco file "new.jst.eco". Current code:

```
class TestApp.Views.NewDivView extends Backbone.View
  el: '.new' # newly created in the initialize method.
  template: JST['new']

render: ->
  $(@el).html(@template())
  this

initiaize: () ->
  $('body').append('<div class="new"></div>')
```

How do I add the contents of the template into the newly created div in the same view?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that :

```
var event_html = template($('#calendar-event-template').html());  // Add apt. selector for template.
$(event_html({title: title, description: description})).appendTo($(el))
```

where :

```
$(el) = $('body .new');
```

will work.
I have not changed the code from reference so that you could search that easily there.
**Refrence :** http://japhr.blogspot.in/2011/08/getting-started-with-backbonejs-view.html

Answer (score 0):

From the [backbone code](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js), `el` is being set first in the `this._ensureElement();` and then `initialize` is called. So I believe here `el` won't be set the way you want it to be. And it will be just a plain `div`.

A solution can be, specify `body` as an `el` for view (may be not the best practice), wrap the content of the template in the `<div class="new"></div>`.

```
<div class="new">
  <!-- put template content here -->
</div>
```

And view you can write like (I don't know coffeescript syntax, hence writing in javascript):

```
view = Backbone.View.extend({
  el : 'body',

  template : "respective_template",

  render : function() {
    this.$el.append(this.template());
    this.setElement(".new"); /* this will change the el for the view from body to a div with class new and will delegate all bound events also if any */

    return this;
  }     
});
```

Our assumption from the code about `el` being set might be wrong, but you can give this a try.